# How to store a variable in an Array using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any function that i can use?

Or i need to create one? Or can i use push? It is modified script from this page:
http://code-maven.com/automatic-counter-using-angularjs

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
    angular.module('CounterApp', [])
            .controller('CounterController', function($scope, $timeout) {
                var timer;
                $scope.stored = [];
                $scope.counter= 0;

                $scope.stopCounter = function() {
                    $timeout.cancel(timer);
                    timer = null;
                };
                $scope.startCounter = function() {

                    if (timer === null) {
                        updateCounter();
                    }
                    $scope.stored.push(counter);
                };

                $scope.pushedVariable = function() {
                    $scope.stored.push(counter);
                };
                var updateCounter = function() {
                    $scope.counter++;
                    timer = $timeout(updateCounter, 1000);

                };

                $timeout.cancel(timer);
                timer = null;
            });
</script>
<div ng-app="CounterApp">
    <div ng-controller="CounterController">

        <button ng-click="stopCounter()">Stop</button>
        <button ng-click="startCounter()">Start</button>
        <button ng-click="pushedVariable()">Push</button>
        {{counter}}
        <p>Stored Variable 1: {{stored[0]}}</p>
        <p>Stored Variable 2: {{stored[1]}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to store what variable where and have what problem doing that?

Comment: you want to push datas in an array? If so, that is already in the code.

Comment: using push is ok, angularJS is a javascript framework and as such every javascript method is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use `$scope.stored.push($scope.counter);` in your function instead of your current `$scope.stored.push(counter);` which is an undefined variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works :)

Answer (score 1):

function(obj) {
        var str = [];
        for(var val in obj)
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(val) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[val]));
}

Where "obj" is your object.